# Writing a mongodb filter with more than one requirement

Tags: python, django, mongodb

How can one write a filter that returns data between a range, less than something, and greater than something else.

Comment: directly in the mongo shell or using pymongo from python or some other method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can specify multiple conditions for a single field using one of the many query operators ([reference](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query-comparison/)) as shown below. In this example, I've specified the `num` field must be greater than or equal to (`$gte`) the `low` value and less than or equal to (`$lte`) the `high` value.

```
low = 100
high = 1000

for doc in exampleCollection.find({ "num": { "$gte": low, "$lte":  high }})
    print doc
```

Where a document in the exampleCollection looks like:

```
{ 
    "_id" : ObjectId("52a248af1d02442354276cfe"), 
    "num" : 500
}
```

And if you haven't created an index for the `num` field as shown, a full collection scan would be necessary to find matching documents (so, you could use `create_index` ([reference](http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.create_index))).

```
exampleCollection.create_index("num")
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution that works directly within the mongo shell. This is not python specific.

```
db.documents.find({ $and: [ 
    { timestamp: { $gte : 111 } }, 
    { timestamp: { $lte : 222 } } 
] })
```

You should consider adding an index on the field you are querying the range on.